# Ember: async hasMany relationship issue

Tags: ember.js, has-many

I'm lost in Ember data promises and hasMore relationships. Here's what I have:

tarifs and reservations are both loaded (with success) at application start:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Em.RSVP.hash({
      tarifs: this.store.find('tarif'),
      reservations: this.store.find('reservation')
    });
  }
});
```

Then, `tarifs` and `reservations` are bounded to `spectacles`:

```
App.SpectaclesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  isLoaded:false,

  model: function() {
      if(this.isLoaded) {
          return this.store.all('spectacle');
      }

      this.isLoaded = true;
      return this.store.find('spectacle');
    }
});
```

`Spectacles` are returned by the server with a `representations` ID array and a `tarifs` ID array. `Representations` objects are returned in the same response, below. `Tarifs` are already in the store, thanks to the first call.

Here's the Spectacle model:

```
App.Spectacle = DS.Model.extend({
  titre: DS.attr('string'),
  sousTitre: DS.attr('string'),
  visuelUrl: DS.attr('string'),
  tarifs: DS.hasMany('tarif', { async: true }),
  representations: DS.hasMany('representation', { async: true })
});
```

Problem is: from what I can see (with the ember browser plugin), `spectacles` and `tarifs` aren't linked (while `spectacles` and `representations` are). The only difference I can find is that they are loaded in two separate server calls, but it shouldn't be an issue, right?

I thought it could be an async/promise issue. My need is, from a representation, to get the first spectacle's tarif. In short: myRepresentation.spectacle.tarifs[0]. I tried various things, like:

```
representation.get('spectacle.tarifs').then(function(tarifs) {
  var tarif = tarifs.get('firstObject');
  console.log(tarif);
}
```

Nothing is working: `tarif` is always null. Seems that all records are loaded, but the relation between `spectacle` and `tarifs` isn't.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, forget it, the problem was in the `tarif` model:

```
App.Tarif = DS.Model.extend({
  nom: DS.attr('string'),
  montant: DS.attr('number'),
  spectacle: DS.belongsTo('spectacle', { async: true })
});
```

The "belongsTo" relation is a mistake, because a `tarif` can be linked to many `spectacles`. I just removed this line, and everything is now fine.